# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor creates new threadPool for each new request

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency

We have a spring application deployed on weblogic server. We have a REST webservice in our project. It is a POST call. In the request body of this webservice, a name comes. When our webservice is being called, internally it calls other webservice using RestTemplate.

Now we need to pass more than 10 names in each request, and in turn our webservice should call the other web service 10 times. We need to make it a multi-threaded call.

So we are using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. The following is the code for the same.

```
<bean id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="3"></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="4"></property>
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true">
    </property>
</bean>

public class ApplicationDirectorImpl{

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;

    ....
    ....

    public CustomResponseObject method(){

    ....
    ....

        List<Future<FutureCustomResponse>> fList = new ArrayList<Future<FutureCustomResponse>>();

        for(String name : nameList){
            Future<FutureCustomResponse> fut = threadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(new Task(name));
            fList.add(fut);
        }

        for(Future f: fList){
            FutureCustomResponse fuResponse = f.get();
        }
    }
}

public class Task implements Callable<FutureCustomResponse>{
    private String name;

    public call() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("name" + name + " performed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return NameBuild.getPersonalInfo(this.name);
    }
}
```

Now when a request comes with 5 names, it should be serviced by these 3 threads.

We have 2 servers, and so there will be 2 instances of our application. So the threadpool will be created for each server or common between 2 servers.
So in total how many threads will be created? 3 per server or 3 per application?

Comment: How would the threadpool be common between 2 servers? Also, what do you mean it creates a new threadpool for each request? Are you claiming that the (single) threadpool isn't used properly for multiple requests?

Comment: Hi, The code worked afterwards, so there is only one threadpool created, so I have edited the question. But the second question still remains. Please help if could throw some light.

Comment: One threadpool per server, of course. One threadpool per JVM after all.

Comment: I was facing one more issue. I want the thread pool to start and create threads once the application server is up. But the threads start when the first request comes. Please let me know what needs to be done in this case.